# findwindow doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So Im trying to create a camo unlocker but I have never had trouble with getting process id through findwindow

but now Im trying to find black ops 2's proc id but the window name doesn't work

Call of Duty®: Black Ops II

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, _T("Call of Duty®: Black Ops II - Multiplayer"));

    if(hWnd){
        cout << "window found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you intend to ship both ASCII and Unicode versions, you really don't need to use the `_T()` macro anymore (and remove `tchar.h`). Just use `FindWindowW` and a wide string (`L""`).

Comment: l2p, noob. Er... I mean... what error code did you get?

Comment: I found the problem, and there where no errors, the thing was that it did not find the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindWindow` works correctly. The possible causes for your problem are:

1. You have an encoding error. You should use the Unicode API:

   ```
   HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Call of Duty®: Black Ops II - Multiplayer");
   ```
2. There is no top level window with that window text. Use a tool like Spy++ to check that.

You should also make sure that you read the documentation carefully. Specifically it states the following:

> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call **GetLastError**.

You should do as it says and call `GetLastError` in event of failure.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the registered symbol could be unicode, you'll want to use [`FindWindowW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499.aspx):

> Unicode and ANSI names
>   FindWindowW (Unicode) and FindWindowA (ANSI)

Alternatively, you could use [`FindWindowEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500.aspx) and search for the window class name.

Comment: `FindWindow()` can also search for class names, you don't need the Ex version for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find the window by class as an application may change its title and class names usually do not have fancy characters. If you do not know them look for some tool (Spy++ + i think it comes with Visual Studio) or create a list with a simple tool using `EnumWindows` and `GetClassName`

Answer (score -2):

FindWindowA worked for me :) so I just changed from tchar to the normal HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("Call of Duty®: Black Ops II - Multiplayer"));

Comment: Not generally applicable, and most certainly not anything, you'd want to recommend. It'll fail faster than you can change your thread's locale back to normal.