# Cannot find window using FindWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, capture, hwnd

I've been trying to capture and copy to clipboard a window using C++. I've managed to make the code work for Notepad, but weirdly enough it won't find other windows that I tried : "Calculator" , "Wordpad", etc.

This is the code:

```
    RECT rc;
HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow(TEXT("Notepad"), NULL);    //the window can't be min
if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    cout << "it can't find any 'note' window" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

//create
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

//Print to memory hdc
PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);

//copy to clipboard
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbmp);
CloseClipboard();

//release
DeleteDC(hdc);
DeleteObject(hbmp);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);

cout << "success copy to clipboard, please paste it to the 'mspaint'" << endl;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't find an exact name match [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) might be a better option.

Comment: Maybe those other windows are specified using wide-character strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FindWindow does not find the a window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530871/findwindow-does-not-find-the-a-window) or [findwindow doesn't work c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407584/findwindow-doesnt-work-c).

Comment: HWND hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(0, 0, "Notepad", 0);

Comment: Note that this is a very fragile way of interacting with windows. The class names are not guaranteed to stay the same. If you need to find a window dynamically, you should use `EnumWindows` or similar functions, as suggested. Better yet, create an interface (similar to Spy++) that allows the user to *pick* a window to screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason that you can't find the windows is simply that you are using the wrong names.

If you read up on the documentation of the [::FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, you will realise that you are searching for windows by their class name. As you mentioned you were able to find Notepad by simply searching for "Notepad", this is expected as the window class is called Notepad. However, not all window classes are so simplistically named. For example the Calculator window class is actually referred to as "CalcFrame" class.

The best way to find the correct names to search for is to use a tool called "Spy++" and using it's find function. This tool is normally available as part of a visual studio installation. Let me know if that helps.

Here is a sample code, that works perfectly.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::cout << "This is amazing..."<< std::endl;

    HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow( TEXT("CalcFrame"), NULL );

    if (hwnd != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Found." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not found." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you :)
It didn't worked when I typed in "CalcFrame".
Also, I've downloaded spy++ 11 and got the result "Chrome Legacy Window" for google chrome - it too, did not work.

Doubled checked with "Notepad" to be sure i didnt accidently ruined the code and everything is still working perfectly.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to add sample code which works as I explained it.